# Salesforce Community

Tags: customer-community

I have created a custom controller which is used to login into salesforce community.  
    `loginPage = Site.login(username,password, startUrl);
    loginpage.setRedirect(true);
    return loginPage;`

My problem is when user click the Back arrow from home page in web browser it is going back to login page. I need to restrict this action how i can achieve this.

Thank,
IRaj.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand the use case here but I believe you can't reliably block a user from hitting the browser back button. You can prompt them using JavaScript

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "Do you want to log out?"; };
```

You can find alternate approaches for handling this in JavaScript [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/how-to-stop-browser-back-button-using-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to  disable the browser back button functionality for all the browser while you can prevent it using following javascript.

function preventBack(){window.history.forward();}
  setTimeout("preventBack()", 0);
  window.onunload=function(){null};

You may also check

if(UserInfo.getUserType() == 'Guest')     return new PageReference('/CommunityLogin');
else     new PageReference('/CommunityHome');

Comment: Hi Gaurav &Vikas , Thanks for your reply. I dont want to disable the back button in browser.  when user successfully logged into the salesforce community it goes to user landing page. My problem is when user gives login page file name is address bar it is going to login page(Don't ask why your are giving the file in in address bar its a part of testing). My requirement is if he goes to login page he should not come back to User home page.